# Switching form one activity to another white screen is shown how to fix this issue? android

Tags: android

Switching form one activity to another white screen is shown how to fix this issue? checked by adding windowDisablePreview true in style.xml
nothing works can any one post the correct solution for this issue.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: share what you have done so far

Comment: It could be because of the reason that you are doing a lot of work in onCreate of new activity being started.